# Using Smartsheet API with Swift

Tags: smartsheet-api

Is it possible to use Alamofire like so:

```
AF.request("https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/",method: .get).responseJSON { Data in debugPrint(Data.result) }
```

in Swift to interact with the Smartsheet API?

I'd hope that swapping out the current https with an reasonable one would do what I want.

I would like to get information from the API. The error thrown is that I don't have authorization for the API:

```
Swift.Result<Any, Alamofire.AFError>.success({ errorCode = 1004; message = "You are not authorized to perform this action."; refId = 1ca40zco0itdd; }).
```

Comment: What do you mean by "interact with the API"? What are you actually trying to achieve? And what's the result you get with your current code?

Comment: The goal is to make an app that will take the current location, some inputs of a user and post it to the Smartsheet API. Also, I would like to get information from the API. The error thrown is that I don't have authorization for the API: Swift.Result<Any, Alamofire.AFError>.success({
    errorCode = 1004;
    message = "You are not authorized to perform this action.";
    refId = 1ca40zco0itdd;
}). I think the swift tag is inappropriate for this question so I'll remove it.

Comment: I think you should edit and update your question instead of writing clarifications in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to understand end points better and read the documentation on Alamofire. I changed my code to the following and it worked!

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
           "Authorization": "Bearer " + api_key_smartsheet,
          "Accept": "application/json"
      ]

 AF.request("https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/?includeAll=True", method: .get,headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
          debugPrint(response)
      }'''
```